# Поздравление участников группы с Днем Рождения

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

В группе состоит больше 30 000 участников. Именинников каждый день больше 50 человек. Каждый день на стену группы публикуется пост с поздравлением и списком именинников. Его приходится набирать вручную.

Вопрос: как можно автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: [Не подходит](http://startler.ru/blog/all/polezny-smm-servis-dlya-pozdravleniy-uchastnikov-gruppy-vkontakt/)?

Comment: Идеальный вариант, просто супер! Премного благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Раз ув-мому ТС подошло, решение следующее — [SMM сервис для поздравлений участников группы Вконтакте](http://startler.ru/blog/all/polezny-smm-servis-dlya-pozdravleniy-uchastnikov-gruppy-vkontakt/). В поле ID группы необходимо ввести или номер или короткое название группы. Можно заранее отсортировать будущих именинников, для отложенных постов. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте описание содержимого статьи. Приложите тот же скриншот, хотя бы.

Comment: Только нужно учитывать тот факт, что этот результат работы этого сервиса не включает тех пользователей, которые используют измененный адрес страницы ВК. Отображаются только те, у которых ВК-ID вида  IDХХХХХХХ. Те пользователи, у кого изменен вид ID в списке не будут. Но все равно, таких пользователей процентов 15-20. И вручную надо добавить только их, что уже на порядок облегчает труд администратора группы.

Comment: @Oggi, ещё раз проверил — не надо ничего добавлять вручную. Пример: адрес страницы девушки во ВК имеет вид [https://vk.com/ladysibil](https://vk.com/ladysibil) , сервис [Её всё равно видит](http://startler.ru/vk/?group_id=chgkrostov&date_start=04.04&date_end=06.04&submit=1) , только под id. Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно дело в количестве участников группы. Там их больше 37000, и количество которое выдает сервис немного не сходится с количеством, если искать по поиску в группе, еще возможно не учитываются забаненые участники. Вечером попробую разобраться.

Comment: @Саша Черных https://gyazo.com/d26f3a5686e60a7d258b410913ffa461 вот количество найденных участников через поиск в группе итог 94, а вот результат найденный сервисом http://startler.ru/vk/?group_id=dwar_game&date_start=04.03&date_end=04.03&submit=1 записей 78.

Comment: @Oggi, я не разработчик. Им пробовали писать? О том, чтобы все 37 с лишним тысяч подписчиков не выводились сразу на одной открывающейся не одну минуту странице, занимая 900 Мб оперативки, тоже бы упомянули. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, к вам я никаких претензий не имею абсолютно, если вам так показалось. Наоборот, благодарен за ссылку на этот сервис. Он уже многократно облегчил жизнь администратору группы. Просто обращаю внимание на эти детали, поскольку считаю, что возможно, кому-то, это будет важно.

Comment: @Oggi, я тоже не имею к Вам никаких претензий :) . И пишу всегда «Спасибо» в конце сообщений, чтобы придать сообщению вежливости, и собеседник не счёл мои слова грубыми. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для автоматизации процесса публикации постов с поздравлениями участников группы с Днем Рождения есть отличный сервис - VKBday
Сервис VKBday – отличный способ напомнить вашим подписчикам о вашей группе и простимулировать их посетить её. Он заключается в ежедневных или еженедельных публикациях поста на стену сообщества с поздравлением всех ваших подписчиков-именинников с днём рождения. Это позволяет, во-первых, напомнить о сообществе вашим подписчикам, а во-вторых, для самых постоянных читателей ленты вашего сообщества – просто сделать им приятное.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/205542)

Comment: как можно добавить источник? если адрес этого сервиса и есть источник.